# SQL Server operating with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, average

I'm trying to make an average of two columns that may or not contain in the second one Null values. Can someone help me get an idea of how to make an operation between these values?

```
select 
    nib, primeiroTitular, segundoTitular, 
    ((YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(P1.dataNascimento)) + 
     (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(P2.dataNascimento)))/2 as média 
from 
    ContasBancarias
left join 
    Pessoas P1 on P1.bi = ContasBancarias.primeiroTitular
left join 
    Pessoas P2 on P2.bi = ContasBancarias.segundoTitular
```

Comment: Well this question is clear as mud. What would you like to happen when one value is NULL? Have you looked at the ISNULL function?

Comment: i would like to turn the null value to 0.

Comment: ISNULL(Your_Column, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Here  is what you can do.  I changed  the way that you do  calculation between the two dates I used the DATEDIFF() function Next time try to indent your code when you ask a question it's easier for the people  when they try to read your code.

```
SELECT nib
   , primeiroTitular
   , segundoTitular
   ,(DATEDIFF(YEAR,GETDATE(), CASE 
                                    WHEN P1.dataNascimento IS  NULL
                                    THEN GETDATE()
                                    ELSE P1.dataNascimento
                              END )  
    + DATEDIFF(YEAR,GETDATE(),CASE 
                                    WHEN P2.dataNascimento IS  NULL
                                    THEN GETDATE()
                                    ELSE P2.dataNascimento
                              END) )/2 as média 
FROM ContasBancarias 
LEFT JOIN Pessoas P1 
ON P1.bi = ContasBancarias.primeiroTitular
LEFT JOIN Pessoas P2 
ON P2.bi = ContasBancarias.segundoTitular
```

Comment: you can remove the first case  it you are sure that only the second column could be NULL .  and you can also change ' THEN GETDATE()' to any value you want to give .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only the second column could be `NULL` try this -

`([Column1] + ISNULL(Column2,0))/2 AS [Average]`

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of accuracy, I would recommend NOT INCLUDING any NULLs in your equation, since NULL means "don't know the value", "don't know what the value is", or "don't know if this value is relevant at all". To assign a zero value to NULL is to skew the results.

Most accurate results, use the WHERE clause to eliminate any row with NULL from the calculations, or the ISNULL function.